# Get Ids from constant list for which there are no rows in corresponding table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a table Vehicles(Id, Name) with below values:

```
1 Car
2 Bike
3 Bus
```

and a constant list of Ids:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I want to write a query returning Ids from above list for which there are no rows in Vehicles table. In the above example it should return:

```
4, 5
```

But when I add new row to Vehicles table:

```
4 Plane
```

It should return only:

```
5
```

And similarly, when from the first version of Vehicle table I remove the third row (3, Bus) my query should return:

```
3, 4, 5
```

I tried with exist operator but it doesn't provide me correct results:

```
select top v.Id from Vehicle v where Not Exists ( select v2.Id from Vehicle v2 where v.id = v2.id and v2.id in ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ))
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Better question is why you hardcode a set of "ID" values. I suspect a design issue here. I suggest you create a view for this "list" and use it where needed in the manner given by Larnu. Then, if it changes (which seems likely) you only have one place to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat your "list" as a dataset, and then use the `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT V.I
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))V(I) --Presumably this would be a table (type parameter),
                                     --or a delimited string split into rows
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                  WHERE YT.YourColumn = V.I);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using `EXCEPT` set operator.

[Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Vehicles TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, vehicleType VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @Vehicles (ID, vehicleType) VALUES
(1, 'Car'),
(2, 'Bike'),
(3, 'Bus');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @vehicleList VARCHAR(20) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
    , @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT TRIM(value) AS missingID
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@vehicleList, @separator)
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM @Vehicles;
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+
| missingID |
+-----------+
|         4 |
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL we store our values in tables. We therefore store your list in a table.
It is then simple to work with it and we can easily find the information wanted.
I fully agree that it is possible to use other functions to solve the problem. It is more intelligent to implement database design to use basic SQL. It will run faster, be easier to maintain and will scale for a table of a million rows without any problems. When we add the 4th mode of transport we don't have to modify anything else.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE vehicules(
> id int, name varchar(25));
> INSERT INTO vehicules VALUES
> (1 ,'Car'),
> (2 ,'Bike'),
> (3 ,'Bus');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ids (iid int)
> INSERT INTO ids VALUES
> (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW unknownIds AS
> SELECT iid unknown_id FROM ids 
> LEFT JOIN vehicules
> ON iid = id
> WHERE id IS NULL;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM unknownIds;
> ```
>
> ```
> | unknown_id |
> | ---------: |
> |          4 |
> |          5 |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO vehicules VALUES (4,'Plane')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM unknownIds;
> ```
>
> ```
> | unknown_id |
> | ---------: |
> |          5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f48228573956506beb8e6aad60b5a465)*